# Ruby Gem ActiveRecord find method with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, sinatra-activerecord

I'm building a Sinatra application using three database tables: `user`, `post`, and `like`.
I'd want to run a query that will find an entry in the `like` table like so:

```
FIND in like WHERE user_id == params[:user_id] AND post_id == params[:post_id]
```

(for one condition, I'll be using: `Like.find_by_user_id(params[:user_id])`)

**My Question**
How to run a *find query* with multiple conditions using the `ActiveRecord` Gem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where):

```
Like.where('user_id = ? AND post_id = ?', params[:user_id], params[:post_id])
```

or

```
Like.where('user_id = :user_id AND post_id = :post_id', params)
```

Is important to keep in mind that the paremeters of the where need to be converted to the expected type for example `params[:post_id].to_i`

Answer (score 5):

Similar to `find_by_user_id` for `user_id` column you can combine multiple column names and get a dynamic finder `find_by_user_id_and_post_id`:

```
Like.find_by_user_id_and_post_id(params[:user_id], params[:post_id])
```

When there are more than "bearable" columns in the `find_by_` finder, you could use `where` and supply the condition as follows:

```
Like.where(user_id: params[:user_id], post_id: params[:post_id])
```

Answer (score 2):

`Like.find_by_user_id(params[:user_id])` - this syntax is deprecated in [ActiveRecord 4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders).

Instead try using `where` method of ActiveRecord query interface, to pass [array conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions). Example:

```
Like.where("user_id = ? AND post_id = ?", params[:user_id], params[:post_id])
```

Answer (score 2):

#### If you are expecting one record to be the result:

To replace `find_by_whatever` you can use `find_by(whatever)` for example `User.find_by(username:"UsernameIsMyUsername",password:"Mypassword")`. You should use `find_by` if there is only one record that you expect to match your search.

#### If you are expecting more than one record to be the result:

If you expect more than one you should use `where` with `where(username:"MyUsername",password:"Password")`. This will return all the resulting records in an array.